# Avoiding method with multiple identical typed parameters

Tags: java, coding-style

I want to avoid passing multiple identically typed parameters into my method to avoid the potential to misorder the parameters. For example:

```
void createBook(String publisher, String illustrator, String author)
```

My instinct is to create 3 new types extending String, so that I can have parameters Publisher, Illustrator, and Author, which can be constructed and used as Strings. However, this isn't possible since String is final.

How can I achieve the Clean Code that I desire in the simplest manner? It seems like overkill to have to implement a base class that provides a constructor and .toString for each of these.

Comment: You can't extend String, since it is final. What you can do, is boxing the String in a new Class.

Answer (score 5):

Create a Book class and make the method accept an instance of Book :

```
void createBook(Book book)
```

To avoid the same problem of parameters with the same type in the Book constructor, you could use a builder or a setter approach.

Setter approach :

```
Book book = new Book();
book.setPublisher(...);
book.setIllustrator(...);
book.setAuthor(...);
```

Builder approach :

```
Book book = new BookBuilder().withPublisher(...)
                             .withIllustrator(...)
                             .withAuthor(...)
                             .build();
```

The Builder approach is more verbose to achieve but note that it also provides clearer client code and  make completely sense if the object is designed to be immutable. It makes it always consistent and thread safe.

Comment: Builder can also validate that all required values are given, and that potential co-dependent values are correctly matched, making it impossible to create an incomplete/invalid book.

Comment: I can't enforce required parameters with the Builder pattern though, it allows constructing an object that may not have an author, illustrator and/or publisher, correct? Typically the Builder pattern keeps required parameters in the constructor, which, as you pointed out, takes me back to the original problem.

Comment: @Andreas I can imagine ways to validate required values with builder at runtime, but don't think we can at compile time. Also any discussion I can find of builder for required parameters suggests its a misuse.

Comment: @TheClassic Your question is not about enforcing required parameters are compile-time, but how to *"avoid the potential to misorder the parameters"*. The solution to that is *named parameters*, which is not supported by Java, but the Builder Pattern is a good way to accomplish the same thing. Yes, you lose compile-time validation of required parameters, but you gain the flexibility of a Builder. Now it's up to *you* do decide which you prefer: Named parameters or compile-time validation of required parameters. Since there may be other runtime-only validations, the builder pattern wins.

Comment: @Andreas unless he switches to Kotlin :-)

Comment: The compiler itself cannot enforce a required value in passed parameters. But some alternative tools can help to detect it. Some ways : 1) IDE features (IntelliJ for example can display the name of each parameter as you want invoke a method) 2) Annotate your parameters with `@NotNull` and set your IDE  configuration to get a compilation error as it detects a violation And 3) the best thing to do : write unit tests

Answer (score 1):

Named parameters are not supported in Java but you can either use a little trick or make a builder-type class like below.

**1-Little trick;**

```
String publisher; String illustrator; String author;
createBook(publisher="...", illustrator="...", author="...");
```

**2-Builder class;**

Based on your method name I named class as Book

```
public class Book {
  public static class Builder {
    public Book build() {
      return new Book(this);
    }

    public Builder setPublisher(String publisher) {
      this.publisher = publisher;
      return this;
    }

    public Builder setIllustrator(String illustrator) {
      this. illustrator = illustrator;
      return this;
    }

    public Builder setAuthor(String author) {
      this.author = author;
      return this;
    }

     private String publisher;
     private String illustrator;
     private String author;
  }

  public static Builder builder() {
      return new Builder();
  }

  private Book(Builder builder) {
    publisher = builder.publisher;
    illustrator = builder.illustrator;
    author = builder.author;
  }

  private String publisher;
  private String illustrator;
  private String author;
}
```

Then you can use it like this

```
Book book = Book.builder()
    .setPublisher("JohnThePublisher")
    .setIllustrator("JohnTheIllustrator")
    .setAuthor("JohnTheAuthor")
    .build();
```